# Call private protocol method that objc class comforms to from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have an old Objective C class

```
// Model.h
@interface Model
@end 

@protocol Observer
  - (void)observer:(ObserverManager *)observerManager someType:(SomeType)someType
@end
```

and then in implementation file

```
//Model.m
@interface Model () <Observer>
@end

#pragma mark Observer

- (void)observer:(ObserverManager *)observerManager someType:(SomeType)someType
{
    if (someType && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]) {
        [self.delegate someMethod];
    }
}
```

Now, I need to write a test to verify that the delegate method `someMethod` will get called. I am trying to write a test in Swift and there is no simple way to mock `ObserverManager` so I am trying to call the method delegate method directly on the model. The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to call

```
- (void)observer:(ObserverManager *)observerManager someType:(SomeType)someType
```

on the model in Swift. Since objc class conforms in the implementation file it's invisible for Swift and it gives me compiler error.

I was trying to have a private objc header where I would make delegate method visible and then include that file into tests bridging file but the compiler still complains. Any other ideas I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are lacking bridging header: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: @NeverHopeless bridging header is set for the test target.